# Support for special Natural Ergonomic Keyboard 4000 hotkeys on OS X 10.11

Tags: keyboard, macos, usb, microsoft

I'm trying to get the special keys on my [Natural Ergonomic Keyboard 4000](https://www.microsoft.com/accessories/en-us/products/keyboards/natural-ergonomic-keyboard-4000/b2m-00012) working under OS X El Capitan. Officially, Microsoft only offers limited support for this keyboard on Mac.

The multimedia keys (mute/volume/play) work, but the home/search/mail/calculator keys don't. The official IntelliType Pro software also lacks a way to configure the programmable hotkeys.

Are there any unofficial tools to get them working?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [ControllerMate by Ordered Bytes](http://www.orderedbytes.com) (costs $25) to regain control over the special keys of the Natural Ergonomic 4000. It should recognise all keys, even the shortcut keys.

Note: To get the "My Favourites" keys working, download the profile at: http://www.orderedbytes.com/controllermate/compatibility/#microsoft/ergonomic_keyboard_4000

Comment: It's a $25 tool, but it matches my requirements.

Comment: Updated answer with mention of price (and link!)
Luckily it has a demo. Try it out before buying! It can be a bit complex at first.